# How to delete one row and update a certain cell in the rest?

Tags: c#, datagridview

[image]

What I want to do is if I click a **delete** button, the whole row will be deleted (e.g Row 1). And then, when it is deleted, the remaining rows will update it's "ID" prior to the value of the deleted row.

For example, I delete *Row 1*, *Row2's* **ID** will become 1 and *Row 3's* **ID** will become 2.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
private void btn_Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string type = (string)dgv_Layers.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value;
        int index = (int)dgv_Layers.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value;
        //MessageBox.Show(index.ToString());
        if(type == "R")
        {
            index--;
            //draw._rectangles.RemoveAt(index);
            dgv_Layers.Rows.RemoveAt(index);
            counter--;
            for(int i =0; i < dgv_Layers.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                index++;
                dgv_Layers.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = index;
            }
        }
        }
```

**UPDATE**

Updated the code. Did the part where I can delete the topmost part and update the remaining rows. My problem now is when I delete in between, e.g. Row 3, the rows updates and the IDs starts from 3. I want it to start from 1;

Comment: In cases like this, you really should be modifying the underlying data, not the cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are using value of index which is already 3.

```
int index = (int)dgv_Layers.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value; //index=3, when you delete 3rd row
```

and then in your loop you are doing like this -

```
if(type == "R")
    {
        index--; //2
        //draw._rectangles.RemoveAt(index);
        dgv_Layers.Rows.RemoveAt(index);
        counter--;
        for(int i =0; i < dgv_Layers.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            index++; //3
            dgv_Layers.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = index; //3
        }
    }
```

No need of using index's value here. you should be using this loop like this  -

```
for(int i =0; i < dgv_Layers.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                dgv_Layers.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = i+1; 
            }
```

This will start values from 1.

or you can do it like this -

```
for( ; index< dgv_Layers.Rows.Count; index++)
{
    dgv_Layers.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value = index+1;
}
```